# Angular drag and drop save location in database and screen resize issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drag-and-drop

I am developing an application where I have one Image one which I am dropping one DIV. Now I want to save that X and Y location to database, so when user comes back position remains same.

Now Problem is if user login to another computer screen resolution might be different and X and Y location is not accurate on that computer.

Can any one let me know how I can resolve that issue.

I want save relative location of dropped div not absolute.

I am using angular, bootstrap.

Comment: Can you post the code in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bipin -

To get the relative location of the mouse cursor, you can use jQuery's event mousemove to get that location:

http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>event.pageY demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    background-color: #eef;
  }
  div {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="log"></div>

<script>
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

To get the relative position, determine the DIV in which you want your location relative to and pass it as the selector (replacing document) in the function that you are applying 'mousemove' to. You can then save that location to your database on the backend and recall it when the user returns to the page.

How you handle when the location wraps or is clipped beyond the current window size, but you can always use scrollbars on your DIV and hope for the best that your users will know how to scroll to see where they put the image.